# How do I prevent a subversion user accessing part of the repository?

Tags: svn, permissions, version-control, perforce

I'm using a Subversion repository hosted on Dreamhost for a project.

I would like to allow access to some users on a restricted basis. At the very least I would like to allow read-only access to some users, but ideally I would like to prevent some users seeing some parts of repository at all. I can't find user permissions mentioned in the web docs for Subversion though I assume it is there?

I'm used to using Perforce, so what I want is what `p4 protect` does for Perforce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the authz file in the conf/ directory. You can set permissions for specific users and specific directories. In svnserve.conf you can specify if anonymous users have read access or not.

Here's an example from a repository of mine:

```
[groups]
project1_team = dave, john, andy

[/]
* =
dave = rw

[/project1]
@project1_team = rw

[/project2]
andy = r
```

What's happening here is that I defined a group of users having full access to project1; dave (which happens to be me) has full access to the entire repository, while andy has read-only access to project2.

Comment: notice that you have to set `AuthzSVNAccessFile <path to authz>` in your dav_svn.conf if you're using apache's mod_dav_svn

Answer (score 3):

On web hosts, there's typically a configuration file (which can be named anything) to run the [authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth). Each repository has a listing like
[my-repository:/]
myuser = rw

Which would give 'myuser' read & write permission on the entire repository. You could also do:

[my-repository/just-this-folder/:]
somejerk: r

Which should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SVN and Apache together , follow the following procedure :

Be aware that the finest permission level you can manage will be on a per repository basis. Assume you have repository1 and repository2

1- Make appropriate user(s) for each repository in a separate file :

```
sudo htpasswd -c -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn_REPOSITORY1.passwd $user_name_for_repository1
 sudo htpasswd -c -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn_REPOSITORY2.passwd $user_name_for_repository2
```

If you want to add more users to each file, remove the -c from the command. because it is just for creating the file for the first time.

2- Edit the following file :

```
nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf
```

you will have a section like this :

```
<Location /svn>
  SVNPath $your svn repository path
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

Copy this block for each repository you have , in our case you need one more block like this . Now, get rid of (delete) the above block and add the following block which are altered copies of the above one :

```
<Location /svn/repository1>
  SVNPath $your svn repository1 path
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn_REPOSITORY1.passwd
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
<Location /svn/repository2>
  SVNPath $your svn repository2 path
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn_REPOSITORY2.passwd
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

3- Save the file and restart the Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific configuration Dreamhost uses, but the typical way of enforcing permissions is to use the Apache authentication mechanisms.  Here's the [relevant page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html) from the Subversion documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/) has your answer [right here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html#svn-ch-6-sect-3.2).

Seriously, people: when has it come out of fashion to read even the most basic documentation before pestering other people?

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer above. However, for Dreamhost specifics, in ~/svn directory there are two files for each repository `repo_name.access` and `repo_name.passwd`. Where repo_name is the name you gave your repository. You can edit the repo_name.access file as described in the accepted answer.

Don't forget to `chmod 644 repo_name.access` after you edit it so that apache can access it.